# How to add a new line after an expression

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file that reads similar to this:

```
random_string
83: some words 45: large error report 326: send emails to certain peple
random_string
34: some words 143: job success
```

I want to target the pattern "#:" (a number followed by a colon) and add a new line after the text that follows it; so it reads like this:

```
random_string
83: some words
45: large error report
326: email certain people

random_string
34: some words
143: job success
```

I've tried a sed commands of:

```
sed "s#'([0-9]*[0-9]:)'#a '/n'#" file.txt
sed "s#'([0-9]*[0-9]:)'#\n#g" file.txt
```

(I don't like using slashes as delimiters, the fence posts make it hard to read)

and an awk command of:

```
awk '/[0-9]*[0-9]:/ {printf "%s\n",$0}' file.txt
```

And neither have worked. I've looked at similar problems posted here and tried their solutions but nothing has worked. I know the answer is most likely very similar and it may even have something to do with the syntax in my number expression but I can't figure it out myself. I have no preference to either awk or sed but I think they would be the best tools at my disposal.

Help?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! For help on formatting your posts see our help page on [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Thanks, and sorry. I knew it looked wonky but I wasn't sure what to do with it. I pinned the link I'm sure it will come in handy.

Comment: No reason to apologize, we were all new once! Now, please [edit] your question to ensure that your desired output is correct. Do you really want those blank lines? And your output doesn't match your description. Why do you have a `FILENAME` as the first line? There's only one `FILENAME` in your input. And how can we know where the filename (if that's what it is) ends? For instance, `83: xyz` has a space after the `xyz`, is that part of the name or should it be removed? Can the file name have numbers in it?

Comment: How does the random string looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a Perl solution:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(\d+:.*?)(?=\d+:|$)/$1\n/g' file
random_string
83: some words 
45: large error report 
326: send emails to certain peple

random_string
34: some words 
143: job success
```

#### Explanation

- `(\d+:.*?)` : match one or more numbers (`\d+`) followed by a `:`, and then the smallest string (the `?` in `.*?` makes it non-greedy, it will stop as soon as the first match is found) matching the rest of the regex. Here, it will continue until the part explained below.
- `(?=\d+:|$)` : The `(?=foo)` is called a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It will match but what is matched will not be included in the actual result. So, `bar(?=foo)` will match all cases of `bar` that are followed by `foo`. Here, we are looking for either a string of numbers followed by an `:` (`\d+:`) or the end of the line (`$`).

Now, the substitution operator will replace all occurrences of the first pattern with itself and  a newline which should give you the desired output.

Comment: @cdruckemiller you're welcome. I added a (rather limited) explanation of the regex as well.

Comment: You could make it `perl -pe 's/(\d+:.*?)\h*(?=\d+:|$)/$1\n/g'` to strip the blanks in between the records (or at the end of the line)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file
random_string
83: some words 45: large error report 326: send emails to certain peple
random_string
34: some words 143: job success
```

You can use sed:

```
$ sed 's/[0-9]*: [a-z ]*/&\n/g' file
```

Output:

```
random_string
83: some words 
45: large error report 
326: send emails to certain peple

random_string
34: some words 
143: job success
```

Comment: This sed command seems to take every word after my target puts it on a new line. I just want a new line to be created before every target input. This is probably, again, my fault for not being clear in the question, and I will edit it again for clairity.

Comment: @cdruckemiller You are right, try to post reliable input, code effort and output. Otherwise we just have to guess.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` seems to do the trick:

```
$ awk '{ for( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) { if( match( $i, ":" ) ) { printf "\n" } printf( "%s ", $i ) } }' /path/to/file
random_string
83: some words
45: large error report
326: email certain people random_string
34: some words
143: job success
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing your input to your output, it seems as if your description of what you want is incorrect.  You say *"I want to target the pattern #: (a number followed by a colon) and add a new line after"* when a more accurate description would be:

- replace the space before any number of digits followed by a colon with a newline.
- insert a newline before every non-empty line not beginning with a digit.
- skip the first line of input because there's nothing that needs to be changed on it.

This `sed` script implements that.  It uses extended regular expressions (`-E`) instead of `sed`'s default basic regex to minimise the number of backslash escapes required and improve readability.

```
$ sed -E -e '2,$ {s/ ([0-9]+:)/\n\1/g; s/^[^0-9]/\n&/}' file.txt
random_string
83: some words
45: large error report
326: send emails to certain peple

random_string
34: some words
143: job success
```

BTW, if there's a possibility of tabs rather than spaces before the `[0-9]+:`, or multiple whitespace characters then use `[[:space:]]+` instead of just a space.  e.g.

```
sed -E -e '2,$ {s/[[:space:]]+([0-9]+:)/\n\1/g; s/^[^0-9]/\n&/}' file.txt
```